# Generate orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ a skew-symmetric real matrix. I can generate a orthogonal matrix by exponentiation:$U=e^A$.
Is it possible to generate an orthogonal matrix from a symmetric real matrix?

Thanks

Fabio

Comment: "unitary real matrices" are called *orthogonal matrices*

Comment: thanks! corrected

Comment: [This thread may help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045178/is-a-0-the-only-solution-to-expa-i).